# Android: Writing and Reading from a File

Tags: java, android, file

I'm trying to write and read a `Hashmap<String, Integer>` with the Help of `ObjectOutPutStream` and`ObjectInputStream`. These 2 are my methods for doing this:

```
 protected void saveHashMap(HashMap<String, Integer> newIDs){
    if (fileIDs == null){fileIDs = new File("IDs.txt");}
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileIDs);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(newIDs);
        oos.close();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

protected HashMap readHashmap(){
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = null;
    if(fileIDs == null){fileIDs = new File("IDs.txt");}
    try{
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileIDs);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        map = (HashMap) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
        fis.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(map != null){
        return map;
    }else{
        return new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    }
```

The problem I have at the moment is that `readHashMap()` throws an `IOEXception` "File not found". Through a bad implementation I have to call `readHashmap()` before calling `writeHashmap()`, but I don't think that's the problem here. I am not really sure why no file is getting created, so I would appreciate your help. If you need any more code I'll add it.

Comment: Why do you want to read something from a file that is empty? That makes no sense.

Comment: you have to create the files using the context methods http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html  ... Also, no way the read method will work if there´s nothing there

Comment: May be I'm wrong but with your code you actually try to write at root of your android device which is probably not allowed. Does it works if you try to write into`new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "IDs.txt");`
with WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions.